# How to use git as a locale version control in android studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

We are an android developer team and we are doing our job on a single server using remote desktop. so everyone of our developers has a user account on the server and all are simultaneously developing using the android studio, we want to use git as version control but our repository must locate on that server not on git remote servers. how can we do that? we are already using Team Foundation Server but it has many problems so we want to switch to git.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you can read some documentation about it to try. This may help: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://gitlab.com. It is free (Community Edition) and widely used.

Answer (score 0):

If you know enough git to for use  local repository /PC ( git init, git add, git commit , git checkout ) , you should not have much problem then. In your server you can prepare a git bare repository under any folder i.e. ( gitServer ) and create a remote on your local repository `git remote ---`. Now you sync up your local git with remote server easily through push, pull, fetch commands..

In case you need to understand git flow for 2-3 members of team, you can refer  stackoverflow post  [How to use git correctly ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892485/how-to-work-wit-git-correctly/40895729#40895729)

Answer (score 0):

gitlab is not proper for you if your group is small. It consumes a lot of memory and resources. I prefer Gogit https://github.com/gogits/gogs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.
I used http://gitstack.com/
it is free for double teams.